# Spoof GPU in Windows 10 Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, gpu

I want to be able to use my Windows 10 Virtual Machine in order to browse the Oculus Store (I am well aware that actually playing games within my VM will be impossible).

Whenever I try to launch the store, however, I get an error message: [Graphics Card Not Found](http://puu.sh/p9BLn/245d23a0fe.png). There is no option to ignore the warning and continue anyway.

I want to make Windows 10 THINK that I have a powerful GPU installed, even though I do not. I know that it's possible to [spoof one's CPU by editing the registry](http://www.tweakandtrick.com/2010/12/change-processor-name-permanently.html), but I can't find any similar instructions for a GPU.

Any help? I'm using Virtualbox on a Mac host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with "spoofing" a powerful GPU is that Windows and applications may try to use the powerful features which, because said features don't actually exist, will cause the whole experiment to fail spectacularly.

Having said that, certain hypervisors (for example [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox)) support [3D acceleration](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-3d) for certain guest OS', so long as you explicitly enable the option and install the 3D video driver in the guest OS. That might be all the Oculus Store needs. VirtualBox's 3D acceleration provides Direct3D 8/9 support so it [should work](https://forums.oculus.com/community/discussion/19489/directx-9-dx9-will-be-deprecated-starting-with-next-sdk) at least for now.

You didn't say what virtual machine software you're running so this is as good an answer as I can give you for now.

Comment: 3D acceleration is already enabled :(